# How to create a dictionary?

Tags: python

I need to plot the results of my code in histograms with subplots:

```
for key, val in plots_train.items():
    print(key)
    count += 1
    plt.title('Source : {}'.format(key) , fontsize=9)
    plt.subplot(nsources,1,count)
    plt.xlabel('Timestamp', fontsize=5)
    plt.ylabel('Network Counter', fontsize=5)
    X=[]
    Y=[]
    X_max = 0
    for train_key,train_val in plots_train[key].items():
        X.extend(train_val)
        Y.extend(range(1,len(train_val)+1))
        results = sm.OLS(Y, sm.add_constant(X)).fit()
        print('params('+str(key)+','+str(train_key)+') = '+str(results.params))
```

This is the result of the print:

```
key: 02141592cc00000003
params(02141592cc00000003,02141592cc00000005) = [6.46004216e-10]
params(02141592cc00000003,02141592cc00000001) = [4.17321446e-19 6.46004215e-10]
params(02141592cc00000003,02141592cc00000006) = [4.17321444e-19 6.46004214e-10]
params(02141592cc00000003,02141592cc00000003) = [8.80603595e-17 1.36315765e-07]
```

I need fro the key 02141592cc00000003 to have:

```
{02141592cc00000003:{02141592cc00000005:[6.46004216e-10],02141592cc00000006:[4.17321444e-19 ],02141592cc00000003:[8.80603595e-17]}
```

Then I want to plot them as a histogram.

Comment: We can't run your code without having the data and the rest of the code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Bazingaa  I have edited my question; I can not put data because I have a huge dataset. My question is related just to the data I displayed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output that you mentioned in your question, you can start by defining an empty dictionary:

```
plot_dict = {}
# print(plot_dict)
# {}
```

In first for loop and before entering the second for loop, add the following:

```
plot_dict[key] = {}
# print(plot_dict[key])
# {02141592cc00000003: {}}
```

Then in the second for loop, after getting the result:

```
plot_dict[key][train_key] = results.params
# print(plot_dict[key][train_key]
# {02141592cc00000003: {02141592cc00000005: [6.46004216e-10]}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much but it just gives me this error  `KeyError: '02141592cc00000001'`

Comment: Could you specify the line that is giving the error?

Comment: `plot_dict[key][train_key] = results.params`   For example in the example that I have the key `02141592cc00000003 `  must have three different train_key  with three different results.params.  So, the key is duplicated

Comment: Yes, I saw that the key `02141592cc00000003` would be duplicated. That is why I used a nested dictionary, i.e. a dictionary inside a dictionary.